# how do i get a variable from a seperate text file

Tags: powershell, variables

Lets say I have a text file full of variables. 
I would like to create a separate file in which I can read and call these variables using powershell.

EX. Variable.txt contains $X=10

Main.ps1 retrieves the variable X from the text file, and doubles it.

Apologize is this is an amateur question, I am very new to powershell.

Comment: Do you expect it to "import" the variable name itself (ie: if you had later lines that referred to `$X`, you'd expect a return value of `20` in other words)?  Or, do you plan to store `10` in a variable within the script, and then be doubled separately into a completely different variable?

Comment: I'd like to "import" it; however if that turns out to be a lot a trickier I can store it as a new variable within the main function

Comment: yep, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

For your specific purpose, you could have a file, `data.ps1` containing your data, like so:

```
$x=10
```

Then, a `script.ps1` file, similar to the following:

```
. ./data.ps1
$x = $x * 2
Write-Host "Value X is $x"
```

Which would give you the following output when you run `./script.ps1`:

```
Value X is 20
```